# Pass function symbol as argument via function or single quote?

Tags: functions, quote

Are `'function-name` and `(function function-name)` completely equivalent, or are there conditions under which I *must* use the more verbose `(function function-name)`?

```
(apply 'message ( list "call func via quote"))
(apply (function message) (list "call func via function keyword"))
```

Both of them yield the same effect. But in many elisp libraries, i am seeing people using `(function func)` to pass function symbols like in [this](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/dired-aux.el#L1305) example.

```
(defun dired-add-file (filename &optional marker-char)
  (dired-fun-in-all-buffers
   (file-name-directory filename) (file-name-nondirectory filename)
   (function dired-add-entry) filename marker-char))
```

Why do people use more verbose way, when they can use just a quote?

Comment: I rephrased the question somewhat so that it would not get dinged for subjectivity.  If I misunderstood your intent, we can roll back the edit.

Comment: This is a nice explanation on the difference between `#'` (aka `function`) and `'`: http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html. Basically, as `C-h f function` says: "In byte compilation, `function` causes its argument to be compiled. `quote` can not do that. IMHO, just use `#'` rather than `'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'foo` and `(quote foo)` are identical: they prevent evaluation of `foo`.

`#'foo` and `(function foo)` are also identical: they extract the function binding of `foo`, including at compile time, which means that the function gets compiled.

So, if you want a *symbol*, use `'foo`:

```
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-local-var)
```

if you want a *function*, use `#'foo`:

```
(setq my-after-function #'my-function)
```

or

```
(apply #'my-function arg1 arg2 others)
```

See also

1. [When to use 'quote in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/850781)
2. [Why sharp quote lambda expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29338004/850781)

Comment: #'foo and (function foo) don't extract the function binding, they just return a symbol. Just try this to get convinced: (type-of (function type-of))
(type-of (symbol-function (function type-of)))

Comment: @memeplex: only in Emacs Lisp and only at this time. Things may change. ;-)

Comment: @memeplex: even simpler:  `(eq 'type-of (function type-of))` => `t` ;)